# Производительность Jboss, Spring

Tags: jboss, spring, java

Добрый день.

Стокнулся с проблемой медленной загрузки страниц.

Есть сервер jboss as 7.1.1 на котором развернут Jasig cas(3.5.1).
При попытке открыть CAS окно логина - оно открывается очень долго. (Я залогировал открытие окна, после получения запроса страницы и созданием страницы проходит 15 миллисекунд, а остальное время(3 секунды) не понятно что происходит)

Есть тот же самый сервер Jbos as 7.1.1 на котором развернуто мое приложение(написано с использование Spring framework 3.2.0.RELEASE), в приложении я использую restfull интерфейсы, при обращении к которому происходит тоже самое. При запросе к урлу, внутренние механизмы отрабатываются быстро порядка 100 - 200 миллисекунд, но запросившая сторона ждет ответа 3 секунды. задержка в 3 секунды проявляется при любом запросе к приложениям которые крутятся под jboss.

Версия java - 1.7.0.51

OS Windows 2008

Памяти для heap выделено 6 гигов

Я думаю, все сводится к настройке jboss или jvm.

Может кто сталкивался с похожей проблемой или подскажете пути решения.

Comment: А какой пинг на сервер? Вполне возможно, что у Вас сервер в Австралии и пинг туда порядка секунды. И такие задержки - будут нормальны.

Также хорошие результаты может дать запуск сниффера и анализ затыков.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте:

1) запросить страничку в firebug и посмотреть на что уходит время (может и правда картинка с лого компании или favicon долго грузятся)

2) прямо у себя в приложении написать простенький запрос, дёргающий это же приложение по внешнему API (тестовый метод, вернёт просто строчку "OK" и залоггирует время). Получив даты отправки запроса, получения запроса,получения ответа может стать понятнее... затык может быть в каком-либо слое, типа логгирования (3 секунды сервер может ждать установки соединения с несуществующей БД логов)